# Change Javascript to only target SVG paths

Tags: javascript, svg

I made an SVG that works great and animates great in JSFiddle but as soon as I put the SVG in Shopify the Javascript that animates the path stops working.

I think it's because the JavaScript I found to animate the SVG is targeting all paths on the page instead of just the paths of the paris SVG I made,

I tried changing the target from `document.queryselectorall('path');` to `document.getelementbyclassname("cls-1");` with `cls-1` being the class of the paths that I want to target, is there code anywhere else I need to change so that this javascript only targets the paths that have the class `cls-1`?

Thanks

```
let drawSVG = function() {
let paths = document.getElementsByClassName("cls-1");
for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
let path = paths[i];
let length = path.getTotalLength();
// Clear any previous transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'none';
// Set up the starting positions
path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
// Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
// picks up the starting position before animating
path.getBoundingClientRect();
// Define our transition
path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
  'stroke-dashoffset 10s ease-in-out';
// Go!
path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}
}

drawSVG();
/* From Modernizr */
function whichTransitionEvent() {
var t;
var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
var transitions = {
'transition': 'transitionend',
'OTransition': 'oTransitionEnd',
'MozTransition': 'transitionend',
'WebkitTransition': 'webkitTransitionEnd'
}

for (t in transitions) {
if (el.style[t] !== undefined) {
  return transitions[t];
}
}
}
/* Listen for a transition! */
var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent();
var transitionDone = false;
transitionEvent && document.body.addEventListener(transitionEvent, 
function() {
transitionDone = true;
document.body.className = "pointer";
});
```

Here is HTML SVG for testing/example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewbox="0 0 361 286" width="100%"><title>test "cls-1"</title><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><path class="cls-1 fill-svg-black" d="M13,301V247h1v-5s3,1,3,3a2,2,0,0,0,2,2s1,0,1,2v16h5V243a3.62,3.62,0,0,1>
```

Comment: how can we test it ?

Comment: was just wondering if there's any other places in the code that target all paths, only want this javascript to work with paths that have a class of "cls-1"

Comment: I think SVG element are in a different Name Space

Comment: added an example of the SVG in question so you can test.

Comment: ah I think I know what you mean, so change getElementsByClassName("cls-1"); to getElementsByClassName("svg-class");

Comment: or `document.querySelectorAll('#Layer_2 path')`

Comment: hasn't worked, interestingly the javascript works when I insert the SVG on the page outside a div, but if I put the SVG inside <div><svg></svg></div> it doesn't work... might just be a shopify issue?

Comment: you have to verify that in your debugger

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, any SVG that is inserted to Shopify with `<style>` and `<script>` inside the SVG won't work, you need to remove the `<style>` tag and `<script>` tag from within the SVG and put them in the **theme.scss.liquid** and **theme.js** or separate file. used Mister Jojo's idea to target the layers instead of all paths which makes the Javascript only target the paths I want, so that technically answered my question as I just wanted to know if any other parts of the code target all paths.